# What are advantages of writing script file in Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

What are advantages of writing commands inside script file and running that script in Dockerfile rather than directly writing instructions inside Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to writing a script like

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

instead of directly writing

```
RUN cmd1
RUN cmd2
RUN cmd3
```

in the Dockerfile. The benefit is that each `RUN` command executes a *separate* script. By writing a single script, you only need to execute *one* script. This gives both better performance, and allows you to share data via variables from one command to the next.